# Java Current Time is 2 hours ahead of my system's Time

Tags: java, datetime, netbeans-6.9, systemtime

I am using following Java code to get current date and time:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
System.out.println(timeFormat.format(date));
```

The Output Time is always 2 hours ahead of my system time or my Time Zone. For example if above code outputs following time:

`11:44:43`

Then my system's time is:
`09:44:43`

Please help me out to solve this problem!

Comment: I'll recommend you to use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), this library has solved most of the Date, Time and DateTime problems that the Java API has.

Comment: Add time zone to your formaytter

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Can you show me here how can i print current date and time separately using Joda Time Library? thanks

Comment: Using Joda Time: `DateTime d = new DateTime(); LocalDate ld = new LocalDate(d); LocalTime lt = new LocalTime(d); System.out.println(ld); System.out.println(lt);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
Date date = c.getTime();
System.out.println(timeFormat.format(date));
```

If it's not working, try to change the time zone. Take a look at [`TimeZone.getTimeZone(String id)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: It is giving same Output. Even I set my own timezone using `Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC+05:00"));` but no success!! Any thoughts?

Answer (score -2):

your problem is Timezone

for exp.

this code for android.

change timezone of app.

because android default timezone is "UTC"

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```